# How to group all crossing paths in a selection in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, stroke, lettering

I am working with handwritten letters and want to select a group of letters and all the ones that come from multiple brushstrokes ("t", "f", etc....) be joined.

I know I can select an individual letter and Command+g to "group" the stokes of that letter.

That's the behavior I want, but I want that to happen with every instance of crossing brushstrokes in a selection.

Thank you.

Comment: There is no "auto grouping" in Illustrator merely based upon overlapping strokes.

Comment: damn...no wonder I couldn't find it. Thanks